# no known instance method for selector 'copy' on protocol conforming to NSCopying and NSObject

Tags: objective-c, nsobject, nscopying

When I compile the code below the line `id copiedData = [_localData copy];` results in the compiler error "no known instance method for selector 'copy'." Given that `_localData` is of type `id<IGTestClassData>` and given that `IGTestClassData` conforms to both `NSCopying` and `NSObject` why does it not have a `copy` method?

IGTestClass.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol IGTestClassData<NSCopying, NSObject>
    @property (nonatomic) NSString* localId;
@end

@interface IGTestClass : NSObject
{
    @protected
    id<IGTestClassData> _localData;
}

    -(void)doTest;
@end
```

IGTestClass.m file

```
#import "IGTestClass.h"

@implementation IGTestClass

-(instancetype)initWithLocalData:(id<IGTestClassData>)localData
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _localData = localData;
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)doTest
{
    id copiedData = [_localData copy];
}

@end
```

Comment: Protocols don't "conform".  You need to have an object class.

Comment: Protocols do conform to other protocols. No issue there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither protocol `NSCopying` nor protocol `NSObject` declares `-copy`.

`NSCopying` declares `-copyWithZone:` only. One solution would be to call `[_localData copyWithZone:nil]`.

Class `NSObject` declares `-copy` even though protocol `NSObject` does not. One solution would be to declare your ivar as type `NSObject<IGTestClassData> *`.